# PHP Mysql - MySQL_Query command not running

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure why, but this line does not even give an error, it simply does not run, and also stops any code after it running. I have checked with die("check") either side of the statement, and only runs before.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE rounds 
             SET `active`='0', `winnerusername`='$WinnerUsername', `winnerid`='$WinnerID', `pot`='$PreviousPot', `paid`='1' 
             WHERE `round`='$CurrentRound' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any idea why it will not run?

Comment: What does the SQL statement look like once all of the variables are substituted in?

Comment: 1. There is no row to update.
2. Something about prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: also do not use backticks ` when you really don't need to ..

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

Change it as

```
mysql_query(
  "UPDATE rounds SET `active`='0',
       `winnerusername`='".$WinnerUsername."', 
       `winnerid`='".$WinnerID."', 
       `pot`='".$PreviousPot."', 
       `paid`='1' 
   WHERE `round`='".$CurrentRound."' "
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @user2924019 try with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE rounds SET active='0', winnerusername='".$WinnerUsername."', winnerid='".$WinnerID."', pot='".$PreviousPot."', paid='1' WHERE round='".$CurrentRound."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$Your_Connection_String);
```

with `$Your_Connection_String` being something like:

```
$Your_Connection_String=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$Your_Connection_String);
```

try to `echo $sql;` below the query and then paste this into a query in PHPMyAdmin or a MySQL Connection program and see what output you get